# Dynamically change TinyMCE configuration

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, tinymce-4

I have used Tinymce in my site. When i am uploading any file (such as Image,Video or other file) then it is uploaded by default folder which has defined TinyMCE config.php file. But problem is multiple user upload at the same time using TinyMCE then all file uploaded this folder, so any user can see all files and save in database. How can i prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do what you desire here ...

TinyMCE's configuration is evaluated in the browser when you call the `init()` method. You can use PHP to create whatever configuration is appropriate as the page is rendered and then load that configuration when TinyMCE is invoked.

The details of what you need to do are very application dependent so what you need to do is not something that we can likely help you with.

Also - the task of saving the uploaded image is something you are doing on the server side so there is no reason you would have to save all files to the same folder.  Your server side code is free to do what it wants with the uploaded files.

Comment: If that resolves the issue can you select this answer so others know the issue is resolved?